# Google My Business verification for vital health service unsuccessful after many attempts

Tags: local-seo, google-my-business

We are trying to get the locations of Marie Stopes South Africa verified. We attempted post card verification, which failed due to post cards not arriving at the locations. Postcards sent through the South African Post Office, the public postal service, often failed to arrive after being sent, which makes this an inefficient process. We attempted phone verification, and we never received the call. All calls to the organization are routed through a central PBX system with one single toll free number, 080 011 7785. We are not sure whether calls from Google's system can be received this way, or if such systems allow automated calls to be received.

The impact of the non verified status of Marie Stopes locations, means that the NGO cannot deliver important female health services, as their target audience cannot find the closest location where these services are available. We urgently need your assistance to ensure that vital community services delivered by Marie Stopes are visible, accessible and discoverable.

In the meantime, we also have issues with illegal abortuion providers creating listings of locations where we suspect ilegal / backstreet abortions are being carried out. Not being able to manage the brand on Google My Business is turning into a real headache that possibly have dire consequences for lots of women

Can you please provide us with options or advice. We tried to get support from Google too many times to mention with no results. We are really at our wits end